# Ruby clockwork for one-time jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork, sneakers

I was thinking about using [sneakers](http://sneakers.io/) as my ActiveJob backend. Unfortunately it does not support delayed messages.
But since we're going to use [clockwork](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork) anyway: is there any mechanism to schedule one-off jobs with `clockwork`? I assume that it would have to be based on the database-backed job feature as the delayed jobs would have to survive application restarts.

Comment: I am not sure about if you can do one-off tasks with clockwork, but i would consider using [after_party](https://github.com/theSteveMitchell/after_party), it's similar to migrations in the sese that it runs only if it hasn't been run before, and this gets tracked in the db

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However I'm looking for a mechanism that isn't tied to migrations or deployments. I.e. anything that lets me use the regular `delay_for` feature of ActiveJob but with the `sneakers` adapter.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't want it to be tied to deployment or migration. It doesn't have to happen at the exact moment you migrate / deploy. You can, inside the deployment / migration task, use `perform_at` to schedule a one-off job at a specific time.

Comment: That's the problem: with sneakers, the `perform_at` functionality isn't available so these tasks need to be scheduled in another way.

Comment: gotcha, sorry to not read the question well enough